# Alternatives to stainless steel staples

Tags: steel, fasteners

I have to mount a glass fibre woven mat onto a stainless steel foil and using staples seems to be the only way to do it. The environment is one where a large variety of solvent vapors will be encountered, and as far as I know no adhesive could survive all of them: alkanes, chlorinated hydrocarbons, alcohols, ketones, ethers...

A regular paper stapler works fine, except for the staples which tend to be galvanized steel at best. Stainless steel staples would seem to be an option, but they don't seem to exist.

Can anyone can suggest a better approach?